# Do the Vedas support the concept of a maiden choosing a husband for herself?

Tags: vedas, marriage, women, samhita

[This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17963/could-you-people-debunk-what-is-written-in-this-website) contains a link to a blog which tries to prove that the position of a Hindu woman is not that respectful in the society.

One of the points it makes is that a Hindu woman can't choose a husband for herself. It has to be her father's choice always.

But, we know from Puranas and Itihasas, that for Kshatriyas at least a bride can be **Swayamvara**. That is, she can choose a husband of her choice among many suitors. So, its not that difficult to debunk this particular claim by that blog.

But my question is slightly different. I want to know if Vedas support the concept of a bride choosing a husband for herself or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the Vedas do support the concept. Given below are two relevant Mantras from the Rig Veda Samhita.

> BhadrA Vadhuh Bhavati Yath SupeshA (1)
>
> Syayam SA Mitram Banuthe Jane Chith (2)  ---  **Rig Veda 10.27.12**
>
> DhAthA DAdhAr Prithivir DhAthA DdhAmuta Suryam (3)
>
> **DhAtAsthA Agruvei Patim DadhAthu PratikAmyam (4)** --- **Rig Veda 6.60.3**
>
> ### Meaning
>
> The bride, beautiful of form attains happy good (1), when she chooses
>   herself a friend as her mate (2).
>
> The Creator sustains the earth, heaven and sun (3). **May He assign a
>   husband of her choice for this lady (4).**

Comment: then why do smritis snatch away her independence?

Comment: Why such question should arise at the first place? Obviously every human is free to act as per his wish. Why to talk about bride? Then next question will be if groom is allowed to choose the bride or not and so on..

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Under some circumstances she can still choose , so the Smritis don't entirely prohibit the act.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, do you ask the same question when smritis ask 'are men allowed to eat before bathing, are brahmins allowed to fight, are brahmacharis allowed to earn money' ? These rules were laid down for men, not for women. *"Obviously every human is free to act as per his wish"* - says who ? If there are 10 rules for a woman, there are 100 rules for a man. Shastras delineate who should follow what based on their nature. For a woman, it is enough to serve her husband to attain same results as what her husband would attain by doing various karma/jnana/bhakti.

Comment: @ram will you only keep talking or start quoting also ?

Comment: @ram i have already openly challenged you that i can counter all your points in a debate.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi quite simply the Smirtis are used based on survival of society and discourage birth based on lust and individual choice. The Brahmana form of marriage where a father chooses a suitable groom was the best because the whole job of marriage was with the goal of birth as well as the ability for a wife to have long-term financial support from her husband. The father's duty was to find this kind of stable groom.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, especially in today's world, but if your ignorance doesn't blind you the atmosphere in ancient times was rough and survival was key not individual choice or freedom look at the comparison between the European Dark Ages and Renaissance/Reformation. The goal of the Smirtis was to assign a moral code for these dark ages which restricted personal choice to ensure all duties were met.